# Q: Using CACLS on a protected file such as WMIC.EXE

Tags: wmic, cacls

I want to change permissions on a protected file.

```
Using WMIC.EXE as an example, I want to change Administrators to F from R.

CACLS c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe

Returns:
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:F 
BUILTIN\Administrators:R 
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:R 
BUILTIN\Users:R 

CACLS c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe /P BUILTIN\Administrators:F 
Returns:  Access Denied
```

This also fails in a batch file called by a RunOnce registry key.

Comment: 1. It would run smoothly in an _elevated_ `cmd` prompt but **use it carefully** using `/E /P`. Without `/E` (edit) option, `/P` replaces specified user's access rights and _removes_ all other users ACLs (as well as `/G`)!!! 2. For Vista and greater **use [iCACLS](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html)**.

Comment: Nope.  

I specifically noted wmic.exe in my example above.
It fails identically to the older CACLS method.

You can test for an elevated command prompt by the command OPENFILES
If it runs, you are elevated.
If not elevated, you are told about it.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR -

```
takeown /f "c:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe" /a
icacls "c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe" /grant administrators:F
```

## Details -

The hurdles here may not be obvious.  The first is the lack of permissions granted to the "administrators" group.  On this file, "administrators" only has read and execute permissions.  So that needs to change. But....how to change when you don't have rights to change?

In Windows, an administrator may always take ownership of a securable object - like a file or directory.  Also, an object owner may always modify the object's security descriptor - even when the security descriptor shows they have no access.  These principals are key here.

So, we're an admin, so we can take ownership of the file, then change the permissions to give ourselves (or anyone else) access.  The `cacls.exe` can't help us with the first part, so instead we'll turn to `takeown.exe`.  The `/f` arg targets a file, and `/a` targets the "administrators" group rather than the single individual running the command.

```
takeown /f "c:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe" /a
```

Now as owner, we are free to add/modify an ACE to the DACL in the security descriptor (aka grant permissions).  We can use either `cacls.exe` or `icacls.exe`, but I always recommend the latter, since the former is decpreciated.  But I'll leave that to you.

```
icacls "c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe" /grant administrators:F
```

Later, after you do whatever you need to... If you want to replace the original permissions, we have to return ownership to "TrustedInstaller", and change "full control" back to "read+execute" for the administrators group.  `icacls.exe` can do both jobs:

```
icacls "c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe" /setowner "NT Service\TrustedInstaller"
icacls "c:\windows\system32\wbem\wmic.exe" /grant:r "administrators":(RX)
```